# How does csc know where to look for standard library DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net

When you compile a C# program, using the command line compiler `csc.exe`, it automatically looks at various .Net standard library DLLs, both the ones always implicitly referenced, and the ones you explicitly reference with `-r`, such as `-r:System.Numerics.dll`.

How does it know where to find them? For example, on my Windows machine are currently 19 different versions of System.Numerics.dll (possibly with some duplicates); how does csc know which directory to look in?

If they handle it differently, I am asking about the command line compiler, not about the Visual Studio IDE.

Also, to the extent that they are different, I'm asking about what happens at compile time (where the compiler needs to read the DLLs for e.g. type checking) and not at run time (where the DLLs are loaded in order to actually call the code).

Comment: The Net libraries are installed which is where the dlls are found.  You can see version from Control Panel : Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features  The path you can find in the VS menu : Project : Add Reference : Net.

Comment: @jdweng Okay, so what does that look like programmatically? How does csc find out which .Net libraries are installed where, and how does it decide which version it should be looking at by default?

Comment: I don't know all the details.  Visual Studio know where the installed library are located.  If you look at the environmental variables (from cmd.exe >Set) you will see a reference to where Net is installed.

Comment: I'm not using csc directly. If we are talking about traditional .Net Framework, the framework assemblies are installed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) under C:\Windows\assembly. The GAC is usable only to store signed assemblies, so it is capable to store multiple versions of the same assembly. Back in the day, it was meant to be a replacement for the traditional shared system32 directory. Using .Net Core I _think_ the compiler is using environment variables, but I'm not sure which ones: I don't use csc directly, but always using msbuild or the dotnet tool.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ended up writing a script to look through all the environment variables that specify directories, to see which ones contain relevant files: https://github.com/russellw/env-dirs

It seems that the two environment variables specifying directories containing the DLL I used as an example, System.Numerics.dll, are PATH and LIBPATH; presumably the latter is the relevant one here.

On my machine, the relevant entry for the latter is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` which does indeed contain what looks like a quite comprehensive set of relevant DLLs.

**Update**: while the environment variables do have these properties, apparently the C# compiler does not actually base its search on an environment variable at all, but on something else entirely, as per discussion on [Does the C# compiler put library options on the command line before or after default ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037400/does-the-c-sharp-compiler-put-library-options-on-the-command-line-before-or-afte)